# Notification action buttons appereance

Tags: android, notifications

How to make the notification buttons to appear as they are supposed to (like on the 2nd notification on the image below)?

This is my code:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(mCtx);
    nb.setTicker("DATART");
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details_select);
    nb.setContentText("DATART text");
    nb.setContentTitle(mCtx.getString(R.string.app_name));
    nb.setContentIntent(getClickIntent());
    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
    nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    nb.setLights(LED, LEDON, LEDOFF);
    nb.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now, "Prihodit", PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, new Intent(mCtx, AuctionProductDetail.class), 0));
    nb.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map, "Mapa", PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, new Intent(mCtx, AuctionProductDetail.class), 0));
    return nb.build();
```

[image: Notification]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I have to set the android:targetSdkVersion to 11 or above

Comment: Is there any way to do this for those of us who have to target lower SDK versions? The action buttons won't show on Android 2.x, of course, but I'd like to style them properly when they are shown.

Comment: You should always target the latest API. Lint will take care of compatibility check and notifies you if you use API that is not on 2.2.